# Could not start bash session after GNU screen window split command

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I am new to GNU screen and was wondering how to split window appropriately.

1. Start a session with `screen` command.
2. Split window with `C-a S`.

And I get the results of the terminal as shown in the image below.

[image]

I'm assuming that I'm logged into bash at the same time as the split screen, is this feasible?

I'm using

- macOS `10.15.6`
- screen `4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06`

Comment: Your display is split, but you only have one window so the new section is empty. You can switch to that region and then either switch windows to show the same thing twice or use `C-a c` to make a new window

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that I need to switch to another window and assign new session and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue sing @Fox 's method.